# jQuery opposite of .hasClass()?

Tags: jquery, class

I am using `hasClass()` to verify in my if statement if an element has a given class.

How can I check in my if statement if an element hasn't a given class? Thank you in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
if (!el.hasClass('foo')) {
  // code
}
```

Answer (score 25):

More generally in javascript, to check the opposite of a boolean result, use the logical NOT operator `!`:

```
var isValid = false;
if (!isValid) {
    // execute if isValid = false;
}
```

For your question, `.hasClass()` returns a boolean if the element has the specified class, so if you have the expression:

```
<div class="someClass"></div>

if ($('div').hasClass('someClass')) {
    // will execute
}
```

to check if it does not have that class:

```
if (!$('div').hasClass('someClass')) {
    // will not get here because our element has the class "someClass"
}
```

---

When selecting elements, if you want to avoid those who have a certain class, you can use the `:not()` pseudo-selector:

```
$('div:not(.someClass)')
```

[About the :not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Comment: There is yet another way to do this. If you want to remove elements from an existing collection, you can use `.not()` (see http://api.jquery.com/not/). Example: `$('.book p').addClass('referenceable').not('.aside').addClass('numbered');`

Answer (score 8):

```
if (!element.hasClass('classname')) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!($('class/id/objct').hasClass('class name'))) {
       //codes here...
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
el.is('.oneClass:not(.secondClass)')
```

if you need check more than one class or

```
el.is(':not(.secondClass)')
```

if you need check only one class.

Answer (score 1):

I will add this answer to the pool in case someone is looking for the same thing that I did and will start with a bit of clarification about .hasClass()

According to the specs:

`.hasClass()` - *"Determine whether **any** of the matched elements are assigned the given class."*

So if I use .hasClass() with a jQuery selector/element that matches multiple elements together with a not statement then it behaves a bit differently:

`!$('selector').hasClass('classname')` would basically translate to - *"Determine whether **none** of the matched elements are assigned the given class".*

Instead in my case *"the opposite of .hasClass()"* translated to - *"Determine whether any of the matched elements are **not** assigned the given class".*

The difference being that I wanted to know if all elements have the class or not. So this became my solution:

```
if($('jQuery selector/element').not('.my-class').length) 
{
    ...
}
```

Basically if there are elements that does not have the class then length will set the condition to true.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

To use chaning, you can use the filter.

```js
$(...some selector...).filter(function (){ 
    return !$(this).hasClass('yourclass');
}).each-or-do-more
```

Comment: `.not()` also allows this: `$(...some selector...).not('.yourclass').each-or-do-more`